# How can I add multiple activity to the same screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-studio

I want to divide my screen into four parts and add activities in each part. I am not interested in using fragment. Each activity should behave independent of other. Attached photo is showing what I exactly want to do.

[image]

In each child activity I want to add VideoView or WebView depending on the selection from menu item.

How can I do it. I didn't find any way to add activity to an activity.
Thanks :)

PS: Activity means Activity not fragment.

Comment: Take a look on GridView.http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Comment: I guess you want to add 4 Fragments, not Activity. Activity has to be one.

Comment: so use a deprecated `android.app.ActivityGroup` `'''A screen that contains and runs multiple embedded activities.'''`, but in your case you should really use fragments

Comment: Action bar is not there in child view if I use fragment.

Answer (score 1):

i strongly recommend 'using fragments' in your case as ActivityGroup is deprecated in API 13..

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can do it by using fragments. Here is the simple example on how to add multiple fragments on single activity [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16034528/3302373)

Edit link

Comment: The link may answer your question, but please add the relevant parts of the code in the link in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this design by using four fragments, one for each child view inside a single activity.
The recommended way is to create a single XML layout for your activity, and create four fragments inside that layout.