# How can I use multiple XML files in a single Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a `Button` in `MainActivity` want to add another XML on Button click event.

Please help me. It would be a very kind of you.

Comment: Post what you done so far

Comment: I have done nothing and i just don't know how to get multiple xml by pressing buttons.

Comment: Why do you want another xml layout ? Why not just create a new TextView ?

Comment: I will use multiple button for getting different text information by using textView. And that's textView will come from different xml file.

Comment: Use [fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033602/how-to-use-fragments-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Simply do one thing in your code define one `Layout` in your `XML` for any kind of `View` which you want to put in run time in XML, then make object of that Layout in your class and inflate another XML in this `Layout` object.

Try this code for inflate another XML in run time:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()); 

// Put another XML name here with R.layout
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.**XML**, null);

// Your Layout object   
    **layoutObject**.addView(view);
```

Answer (score 1):

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
  // Instead of setcontentview() i am restarting the activity.
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

Layout.java

```
public class Layout extends Fragment{


public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);

    return v;
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/RL">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fbb">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note: Creating a fragment java class for other xml(in this case layout.xml) is necessary otherwise setContentView(R.layout.YourLayout) will not work and the app will crash immediately when opened.

Comment: If i wants to get back on activity_main XML by pressing back button then what i need to do ?

Comment: Take a look at the edited MainActivity.java

Comment: Yeah it's working but there have a problem. When it goes through to the activity_main back then the back button and the button that we crated does't work anymore.

Comment: Restart the Main activity instead of using setContentView()

Comment: Is there any way to call activity_main from the fragment ?

Comment: Are you talking about just the xml or the whole main activity?

Comment: Yeah it's about main Activity.