# How do i open fragment from fragment (kotlin)

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, onclicklistener, drawerlayout

I'm finding a way to move fragment to fragment by using `ClickListener`; but I have no idea how to move fragment to fragment.

I want move like this :

A fragment have 4 cardview

click 1 cardview : move to fragment B
click 2 cardview : move to fragment C
click 3 cardview : move to fragment D
click 4 cardview : move to fragment F

I have done fragment move to activity by using code below

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        power655Card.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent (getActivity(), Power655Activity::class.java)
            getActivity()?.startActivity(intent)
        }
```

Comment: Can you please explain which fragment you move to. You explain that you move something TO a fragment; but which fragment is moving when you click on 1cardview ?

Comment: Are you asking how to navigate between fragments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Fragments in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033602/how-to-use-fragments-in-android)

Answer (score 10):

In **Kotlin**, if you want to load various fragment inside activity, you can make one function which you call wherever required to load the fragment.

```
private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.fl_main, fragment)
    transaction.disallowAddToBackStack()
    transaction.commit()
}
```

And if you want to load fragment from a fragment,

```
    val transaction = activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.fl_main, SecondFragment())
    transaction.disallowAddToBackStack()
    transaction.commit()
```

In the above code spinnet, SecondFragment() is the instance of the fragment which you wish to load. So we can also pass the instance of the fragment as shown above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()` to make the fragments transactions you need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can change fragment putting this in you listener:

```
val fragmentB = FragmentB()
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.layout_container, fragmentB, "fragmnetId")
             .commit();
```

`R.id.layout_container` is the fragment container in you activity xml

`fragmentId` is the id of the fragment so you can refer to it later.

Answer (score 0):

```
val fragmentB =FragmentB()
activity?.getSupportFragmentManager()?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.layout_container, fragmentB, "fragmnetId")?.commit();
```

Comment: You should add explanation.